# Валидация модели в Django

Tags: django

Не смог нагуглить. Как можно в валидаторе на модели проверить, добавляется запись, или редактируется? Валидацию применяю в описании модели:

```
filename = models.FileField(upload_to='files', validators=[validateDublicateFile])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если id уже есть — редактируется.

Comment: Благодарствую!

Answer (score 1):

В валидаторе поля - никак, поле не знает, в какой модели оно используется (или вообще отдельно от модели).